# facelets skins are not assigned after reRender to surrounding panel

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I have a table with `<a:commandLink>` that opens `<rich:modalPanel>` with additional info on the selected item. It works using reRendering modalPanel's inner `<a:outputPanel>` on click on the commandLink. Now the issue that all my facelets become usual input items (i.e simple selects instead of comboboxes) after reRender. Is there any way to make the server add the ui info to the reRendered result?

**UPD** I see the following messages in log

10:55:30,483 INFO  [facelet] Facelet[/account/registration.xhtml] was modified @ 10:55:30 AM, flushing component applied @ 10:54:36 AM

**UPD2** The issue happens only with the components that replace usual select, like selectOneMenu or selectonelistbox.

Code examples:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="fieldPropertiesPanel" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Customize Field" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink value="#"
                onclick="#{rich:component('fieldPropertiesPanel')}.hide(); return false;">
            X
        </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>
        <rich:panel id="fieldPropertiesContent">


            <s:decorate styleClass="itemType" template="/layout/edit.xhtml">

                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{accountHome.currFieldType}">
                    <s:selectItems itemLabel="#{fieldType}" itemValue="#{fieldType}"
                        label="#{messages['ProjectFieldType_enum.'.concat(fieldType)]}"
                        value="#{accountHome.projectFieldTypes}" var="fieldType" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </s:decorate>


        </rich:panel>
    </rich:modalPanel>
```

and the calling commandLink

```
<a:commandLink value="Edit" oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('fieldPropertiesPanel');"
                        reRender="fieldPropertiesContent" />
```

Comment: you sure not getting any errors in the server/client side ?

Comment: It would be good if you show some code (a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be better) and the JSF version your working with, at least the word *reRender* gives the idea that you're using RichFaces 3.3.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have added relevant code parts. No there are no errors neither client nor server ones.